# binding property of two instances of same class, non wpf

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class, and many instances of it. I need to bind a property of one instance to another. So in my example I need Symbol property of instance b to be binded to Symbol of instance a. So if a.Symbol is changed, b.Symbol would change immediately. What is the easiest solution?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var a = new MyClass ();
            var b = new MyClass();
            a.Symbol = "A";
            b.Symbol = a.Symbol;    // Not work!
            a.Symbol = "B";
            MessageBox.Show(b.Symbol);

        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        private string _symbol;

        public string Symbol
        {
            get { return _symbol; }
            set
            {
                _symbol = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if this worked for you please mark this as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this .. By Adding additional property on MyClass and tell the class that b obj is dependent on a obj. And in the setter of symbol update the dependent object symbol

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var a = new MyClass ();

        var b = new MyClass();
        a.DependentObj = b;
        a.Symbol = "A";
        //b.Symbol = a.Symbol;    // Not work!
        a.Symbol = "B";
        MessageBox.Show(b.Symbol);
    }


}

   public class MyClass

{

    private MyClass _dependentObj;
    private string _symbol;

    public MyClass DependentObj
    {
        get { return _dependentObj; }
        set
        {
            _dependentObj = value;

        }
    }

    public string Symbol
    {
        get { return _symbol; }
        set
        {
            _symbol = value;
            //Here add the update code
            if(DependentObj !=null)
            {
                DependentObj._symbol = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do exactly what you want. a.Symbol and b.Symbol used to point to same value, but as soon as you changed the value of a.Symbol, that's it, they are now different.

You can achieve what you want if you keep a.Symbol and b.Symbol pointing to the same object, and change that object.  You can't do it with strings because strings are immutable.  But you can use some wrapper around string - I'm going to use StringBuilder here because it's built in:

```
a.Symbol = new StringBuilder("a");
b.Symbol = a.Symbol;
a.Symbol.Clear();
a.Symbol.Append("b");
b.Symbol.Dump();
```

Of course, instead of using StringBuilder, you can use your own wrapper.  You can even use [Implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2(v=vs.71).aspx) operator overloads to convert it from string automatically.